# gio UI. how to make fullscreen

Tags: go, user-interface

I want to make a full screen window using the Gio UI framework.
But the application is in windowed mode all the time.

As I understood it, this code was supposed to result in a full screen application.

```golang
func main() {
    go func() {
        w := app.NewWindow(app.Title("fullscr"),
            app.Fullscreen.Option(),
            app.Decorated(false),
        )

        if err := draw(w); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()
    app.Main()
}
```

Comment: The options of the `NewWindow` are explcitly documented as merely delivering hints to the WM (or whatever thing is tasked with the window placement etc), so it's kind of expected that this thing does not work. I would try to call [`Perform`](https://pkg.go.dev/gioui.org/app#Window.Perform) with the appropriate action after `draw` returns and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @kostix and his comment, I found a solution. I placed `w.Option(app.Fullscreen.Option())` in `draw` function